# RecurrenceTable two difference equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations

I have tried to use RecurrenceTable to Solve a system of two differential equations. I look for having a sequence of the two variables n (population growth factor) and w (wages). I have provided initial conditions for n and w and the parameters I use. However, RecurrenTable does not give any results but runs for a very long time. I have tried to solve my system for the first iteration and I can obtain some results. As a consequence, I do not understand why RecurrenceTable can not solve it. You'll find my code below:

```
humanK[w_] := 2.9985119884257436`*^-7 (-4.297187`*^6 + 905580.` w + Sqrt[9.10441912969`*^11 + w (1.67789538072`*^12 + 8.200751364`*^11 w)]);earlyf[h_,    w_] := \[Delta]1/(\[Phi]1 (1 + \[Delta]1)) (1 - (\[Phi]1 \[Mu]1)/\ \[Delta]1 - h/w)
earlyf2[w_] := earlyf[humanK[w], w] /. param2 // FullSimplify;
param2 = {\[Alpha] -> 0.3, pi -> 0.9, \[Delta]1 -> 0.4, \[Mu]1 -> 0.1, \[Mu]2 -> 
0.32, \[Phi]2 -> 0.4, \[Beta] -> 0.6, \[Epsilon] -> 
0.65, \[Delta]2 -> 0.22, \[Phi]1 -> 2, A -> 2};
dynamics2 = RecurrenceTable[{n[t - 1] (1 - \[Phi]1 earlyf2[w[t]] + 1 + \[Epsilon] humanK[w[t - 1]] - pi \[Phi]2 latef[humanK[w[t - 1]]]) (w[t]/((1 - \[Alpha]) A))^(1/3) == w[t - 1]/n[t - 2] ((pi \[Beta] + \[Epsilon] humanK[w[t - 2]] + \[Phi]2 \[Mu]2)/(1 + \[Beta] + \[Delta]2) + ((1 - pi) \[Beta] (1 + \[Epsilon] humanK[w[t - 2]]))/(1 + \[Beta])) /. param2, n[t] == earlyf2[w[t]] + latef[humanK[w[t - 1]]] pi/n[t -1] /. param2, n[-1] == 0.01, n[-2] == 0.01, w[-1] == 2.2, w[-2] == 2}, {w, n}, {t, 0, 10}];
latef[h_] := (\[Delta]2 (1 + h) - \[Mu]2 \[Phi]2 (1 + \[Beta]))/(\[Phi]2 (1 + \[Beta] + \[Delta]2));
```

Could you help me and tell me why it does work? Do I made a mistake with the code? I have tried to look for some answers on StackExchange on previous questions, but I cannot solve the issue with my code. Thank you in advance,

Comment: I get the error `RecurrenceTable::rtnc -- The number of constraints or initial conditions given, 4, should be the same as the total order of the system, 3.`  Maybe a typo in your code?  Also, I guess these are difference equations, not differential equations.

Comment: Thanks Chris ! Indeed, I do not need to given initial conditions n[-1], you are right. Also, it is difference equations rather than differential. Nonetheless, even after correcting for initial conditions, mathematica runs but does not give any results.

Comment: Your `earlyf2` depends on `earlyf`, could you add the definition for the latter too?

Comment: Hi @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, earlyf is written as follows:  `earlyf[h_, 
  w_] := \[Delta]1/(\[Phi]1 (1 + \[Delta]1)) (1 - (\[Phi]1 \[Mu]1)/\
\[Delta]1 - h/w)` Then, I obtain earlyf2 by plugging `h=humanK[w]`into earlfyf.

Comment: Please modify the question accordingly. I mean, it should not throw the error mentioned in the first comment, and definition of `earlyf` must be present. By the way, the latter definition seems to contain a redundant `\`

Comment: Thanks @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, I have modified the initial post following your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is still unclear but let me suggest a workaround anyway.

Set

```
humanK[w_] := 2.99851*10^-7 (-4.29719*10^6 + 905580 w 
    + Sqrt[9.10442*10^11 + w (1.6779*10^12 + 8.20075*10^11 w)]);
earlyf[h_,w_] := δ1/(φ1(1 + δ1))(1 - φ1 μ1/δ1 - h/w);
param2 = {α -> 0.3, pi -> 0.9, δ1 -> 0.4, μ1 -> 0.1, μ2 -> 0.32, φ2 -> 0.4, β -> 0.6, 
    ε -> 0.65, δ2 -> 0.22, φ1 -> 2, A -> 2};
earlyf2[w_] := earlyf[humanK[w], w] /. param2 // FullSimplify;
latef[h_] := (δ2(1 + h) - μ2 φ2 (1 + β))/(φ2 (1 + β + δ2));

eqs =
 {
   n[t - 1](1 - φ1 earlyf2[w[t]] + 1 + ε humanK[w[t - 1]]
     - pi φ2 latef[humanK[w[t - 1]]]) (w[t]/((1 - α) A))^(1/3) == 
    w[t - 1]/n[t - 2] ((pi β + ε humanK[w[t - 2]] + φ2 μ2)/(1 + β + δ2)
     + ((1 - pi) β (1 + ε humanK[w[t - 2]]))/(1 + β)), 
   n[t] == earlyf2[w[t]] + latef[humanK[w[t - 1]]] pi/n[t - 1]
 } /. param2

out = {n[-2] -> .01, w[-2] -> 2, n[-1] -> .01,  w[-1] -> 2.2}
```

Then you can just iterate:

```
Do[
   out = out \[Union] First@Solve[eqs[[1]] //. t -> k //. out];
   out = out \[Union] First@Solve[eqs[[2]] //. t -> k //. out],
  {k, 0, 10}
]
```

The result

```
TableForm[Prepend[Table[{k, n[k], w[k]} /. out, {k, -2, 10}], {t, n[t], w[t]}]]
```

is this:

```
|t  |n[t]        |w[t]         |
|---|------------|-------------|
|-2 |0.01        |2            |
|-1 |0.01        |2.2          |
|0  |6.95136     |1.30852*10^11|
|1  |2.78041*10^9|17677.8      |
|2  |-0.00520365 |152.063      |
|3  |-4243.91    |0.00617452   |
|4  |0.717483    |0.198168     |
|5  |0.440254    |0.188684     |
|6  |0.202424    |0.198426     |
|7  |-0.481408   |0.22558      |
|8  |1.36723     |0.156763     |
|9  |0.594717    |0.186253     |
|10 |0.358851    |0.192167     |
```

Note however that I used your `n[-1] -> .01`, and later in a comment you said you actually do not want to fix `n[-1]`. If this is the case, then you should do

```
out = {n[-2] -> .01, w[-2] -> 2, w[-1] -> 2.2}
```

and

```
Do[
 out = out \[Union] First@Solve[eqs[[2]] //. t -> k - 1 //. out];
 out = out \[Union] First@Solve[eqs[[1]] //. t -> k //. out],
 {k, 0, 11}
];
```

the result is quite different:

```
|t  |n[t]      |w[t]   |
|---|----------|-------|
|-2 |0.01      |2      |    
|-1 |4.06751   |2.2    |
|0  |0.0110253 |1944.85|
|1  |26031.9   |65338. |
|2  |0.365511  |152.586|
|3  |60.9552   |144.29 |
|4  |0.340298  |142.625|
|5  |61.1481   |149.287|
|6  |0.351272  |143.464|
|7  |59.5907   |148.983|
|8  |0.359834  |143.405|
|9  |58.1481   |148.834|
|10 |0.36851   |143.394|
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ მამუკა ჯიბლაძე that's great! I can run your code and obtain the same results. As you righfully noticed, I have chosen `n[-1]=1`eventually. How can I exctract a list of `w`and `n`from the Table? Should I use List or something likewise?

Comment: @NatachaR Just do `Table[{k, n[k], w[k]} /. out, {k, -2, 10}]`, this will give you the list of the `n` and `w` values

Comment: Thanks a lot again @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე ! It seems to work now. All the best,